# Excel Web App and Data Refresh SP Online and On-Prem

Tags: office-365

My apologies if this type of question has asked many times in the past.

I have an Excel file and create a connection by Data->From Other Sources->From oData Data Feed. (I can alternatively create a connection via PowerPivot->Manage->From Data Service->From oData Data Feed)

I then create my Pivot Table or Pivot Chart according to the many tutorials available online. I then upload the Excel file to SharePoint Online. (Or SP 2013 On-Prem) I am able to view the spreadsheet via Excel Web App. Great.

However, when I attempt to refresh the data, it gives me an error.

```
An error occurred while working on the Data Model in the workbook. Please try again. 
We were unable to refresh one or more data connections in this workbook.
```

The following connections failed to refresh: 
    DataFeed_3_nntechsolutions-sharepoint-com items 
Hide technical details

```
Connection: DataFeed_3_nntechsolutions-sharepoint-com items 
Error: Errors in the high-level relational engine. The following exception occurred while the managed IDbCommand interface was being used: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.. 
An error occurred while processing table 'items'. 
The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.
```

Some pertinent information.
I have an Office 365 Developer Subscription.
The Spreadsheet was created using Excel 2013 as part of the Office 2013 Pro Plus suite.

Also, I am having a difficult time getting this to work with SharePoint 2013 On-Prem. Same type of thing. I create the Spreadsheet, upload, and am able to view it. But I cannot refresh it. I've tried the whole Application Id route with SSS and Excel Services but no dice!

Comment: I found this. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424405.aspx. So I issued the command New-SPWOPISuppressionSetting -extension xlsx -action edit. It opens up in xlviewer.aspx but I'm still facing the same problem of not being able to refresh.